# max-width of child inside a relatively positioned sup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into an issue with bootstrap popovers, and I am trying to style my way around it.  The issue is that the child content, does not fill the parents width if its nested within a span.  Bootstrap styles span by using position relative.

The only work around I have is to set a static width on the .popover class.  Is there any way to style around this? I'm assuming the issue has to do with the sup being `display:inline` but if I change it obv, the `<sup>[1]</sup>` will break lines.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/xFrje/)

---

html:

```
<div class='parent'><p>I need the text to look normal <sup class="reference">[1]</sup> every where</p></div>
```

---

js:

```
$('.reference').html($('.reference').html() + "<div class='test'>" +
    "<h3>Title</h3>" +
    "THis is my random text, that I need to be almost, about this length, maybe a little more... well yea this is enough.<em>Thanks.</em> 6. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">[pdf]</a>" +
    " </div>");
```

---

css:

```
sup {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.5em;
}
.parent {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.test {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1010;
    display: none;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    white-space: normal;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/xFrje/3/

Comment: @Ani the text after the sup is missing...

Comment: are you sure that's how popover works?  The example on the bootstrap documentation has the popover div appear after the inline anchor tag in the document tree.  It also assigns the left and top attributes (presumably after using js to calculate them).  My assumption is that the sup can be inline and the js library for popover will handle the positioning.

Comment: Okay. Is this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/xFrje/8/

Comment: @Nix see here: http://jsbin.com/iyifug/1/ That demo (albeit terribly thrown together) demonstrates the popover and having the inline element have a position relative.  popover elements are not the child of their triggers' but of their triggers' parent container. (http://jsbin.com/iyifug/1/edit)

Comment: Last comment I promise. the doc page can be found here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Comment: @JosephMarikle I am 100% sure my source is correct. I did not show the anchor around the [1] to simplify things. My setup is `sup a.`  The popover is setup on the anchor.

Comment: @Nix in which case you can either change the set it up to be `a sup` or have the popover trigger on the `sup`.  Either should work.

Comment: @JosephMarikle not sure why you continue to talk about placement, but I can not place the popover on the sup, because there could be multiple links within sup.

Comment: @Nix I see. I figured you had control over the markup as well.  If you did, then the possibility of adding the popover class to those items or breaking those items up into several anchor tags with `sup` child nodes would have been an option.  Otherwise all you can do is hacks and such.  I didn't try it but maybe you can set the `a` node to `display:inline-block` with a negative top margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job, though superscripts aren't quite as high as they were:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xFrje/7

```
sup {
    position: static;
}
```